# How to build Ionic Framework in Android Platform?

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I new in Ionic Framework so I just followed in getting started page on their page..
http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/

So I start a new project and I want to try to build it before to try how to make it an androids apps and I followed a tutorial (here: http://ccoenraets.github.io/ionic-tutorial/build-ionic-project.html) but sad to say I got an error when i try to build my project?

This is the error

[image]

What does it mean and why am I getting this error..I just followed the instruction.. I installed Android Studio as tutorial required.
Where did I get wrong?

Comment: As you can see, this is an error related to ANT. You must first install and setup complete cordova development environment in your machine.. Find more details here :https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html

Comment: Ah I see ok I will try to fix it first then I'll be back.. Thanks..